# ASP .NET C# - Format a MySQL date field properly in a listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

My MySQL database has a date field in the format:

**yyyy-mm-dd**

but in ASP .NET this shows as:

**9/14/2009 12:00:00 AM**

in both the ItemTemplate and EditItemTemplate.

How do I format the field to display properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ToShortDateString() method of DateTime.
You also can use something like this:

```
DateTime dateTimeObject = Convert.ToDateTime("9/14/2009 12:00:00 AM");
dateTimeObject.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    qry = "select taxpercentage from tbl_tax where effectivedate contains '" + dt+ "'";
    con.returnscalar(qry); what is wrong in this
```